# Understanding gdalwarp reprojection

Tags: geotools, gdalwarp

My file is

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 0001.TIF
Size is 8512, 8622
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32631"]]
Origin = (837903.261500865686685,5877808.477226150222123)
Pixel Size = (30.079329235631686,-30.079329235631686)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  837903.262, 5877808.477) (  8d 1'48.79"E, 52d56'35.71"N)
Lower Left  (  837903.262, 5618464.501) (  7d46'39.67"E, 50d37'11.83"N)
Upper Right ( 1093938.512, 5877808.477) ( 11d48'11.42"E, 52d43'20.22"N)
Lower Right ( 1093938.512, 5618464.501) ( 11d21'56.03"E, 50d24'59.35"N)
Center      (  965920.887, 5748136.489) (  9d44'38.52"E, 51d41'24.52"N)
Band 1 Block=8512x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

After reprojecting it to EPSG:32632 by

`gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:32632  0001.TIF 0001_.TIF`

I got

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 0001_.TIF
Size is 9192, 9293
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (413533.214507141499780,5866398.182513756677508)
Pixel Size = (29.999953551392952,-29.999953551392952)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  413533.215, 5866398.183) (  7d42'47.95"E, 52d56'24.88"N)
Lower Left  (  413533.215, 5587608.614) (  7d46'56.92"E, 50d26' 2.84"N)
Upper Right (  689292.788, 5866398.183) ( 11d48'55.18"E, 52d54'49.85"N)
Lower Right (  689292.788, 5587608.614) ( 11d39'51.06"E, 50d24'35.94"N)
Center      (  551413.001, 5727003.398) (  9d44'37.73"E, 51d41'29.87"N)
Band 1 Block=9192x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I calculated myself (using Java GeoTools) that

> 413533.215, 5608276.425 EPSG:32632 =
>
> 837903.262, 5618484.501 EPSG:32631

why I get such a big difference: 5587608.614 instead of 5608276.425?
How does gdalwarp determine the pixel size and the extents?

EDIT:

The accepted answer shed light on my confusion. After I reprojected the lower right corner of the source raster instead of the lower left one, I got almost the same numbers:

```
x: 1093938.5119545625
y: 5618464.500556534
[668055.0297114132, 5587613.552738925]
```

`x` and `y` are the original coordinates in EPSG:32631

Comment: the valid area of one or the other of those projections probably fails to intersect the raster so you are likely to see all sorts of distortion and errors

Comment: Probably, but I would like to know how `gdalwarp` does the calculations

Comment: did you look at the code yet?

Comment: I suppose there should be an algorithm or some considerations documented in a natural language...

Comment: Gdaltransform http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html gives `837903.261858582 5618464.50194627` as a result which proves that the algorithm has very little to do with your confusion. Please look at the image and accept the answer by @AndreJ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just display your raster in a GIS software in UTM 32N:

[image]

You see that the raster is rotated in the new CRS, and the former Lower Left point is not the most southward point anymore.

Since gdalwarp always produces a rectangle parallel to the axes of the new projection, the new corner points are different from the UTM31N corner points.